# Is there any way to re-obtain deleted achievement items?

Tags: steam, achievements, team-fortress-2

A few months ago, I finally made my first purchase in TF2 and my backpack expanded accordingly. However, during my years as a F2P, I accumulated a large number of achievement items. Since I only had fifty slots and I cared most about having good weapons, I ended up deleting many achievement items (and the vast majority of random drops).

I've since found/traded for the few achievement weapons that I deleted, but I'm still missing three key items that I deleted and I'd like to have back: The Ghostly Gibus, Pyrovision Goggles, and the Headless Horseless Horseman's Haunted Scrap Metal, all of which I earned by getting the corresponding achievements. There's no way to earn an achievement twice (AFAIK), and these items are tied to the achievements themselves. So, is my Gibus forever lost, or is there some way I can find it again?

Comment: I had this problem also during my F2P days, I just traded items with a friend who then gifted me the items or gave me duplicate drops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to your title, since all achievement items are server based, you cannot get achievement items back once you get rid of them.

However, the items you have listed that you want to get back can be easily obtained.  Here's how:

- **The Ghastly Ghibus** can still be traded for

  - There are 4 ghibuses, one that is a robotic version
  - If you want the look of the ghostly ghibus solely, you can opt to get the *Ghastlier* and *Ghastlierest Ghibus* and change the style. If you're aiming for the actual *Ghastly Ghibus*, there is no way to get it.

    - *Ghostly Ghibus* (has only 1 style, ghostly)
    - *Ghastlier Ghibus* (has 2 styles, ghastlier and ghostly)
    - *Ghastlierest Ghibus* (has 3 styles, ghastlierest, ghostly, and ghostly)

      - This is the most cost effective option
      - It's cheap and can change styles to the 2 older hats
    - *Galvanized Ghibus* (no styles)
- **Unique** (*yellow*) quality Pyrovision Goggles can be traded for

  - but are more expensive than a [**Vintage** (*blue*) quality Pyrovision Goggles](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Vintage%20Pyrovision%20Goggles)
- The **Headless Horseless Horseman's Haunted Scrap Metal** can also be traded for. Users can giftwrap it and send it to you, so you can trade for it.  There also exists clean (tradable) Haunted Scrap Metal that can be traded without gift wrap.

So here's my advice for you:

- Do you have no money?

  - Get a **Ghastlierest Ghibus**. It is the most cost effective option

    - You can switch styles to that of Ghastly, to Ghastlier, or to Ghastliest, without the need to buy 3 seperate hats
  - Get a **Vintage Pyrovision Goggles**.

    - You can pretty much afford one from selling just 1 - 3 trading cards.
  - Don't get Haunted Metal Scrap, instead, try to opt for the Headtaker that is untradable

    - Prices are rather expensive in this case
    - Even getting the hat (Spine-Cooling Skull) and weapon (HHHH's Headtaker) are also relatively expensive in this case.

      - The Headtaker can be upwards of 1 ref (+ $1.99 USD Giftwrap) for untradable, 3 keys for tradables.

The other option:

- Do you have money?

  - Get a **Ghastlierest Ghibus**. It is still the most cost effective option

    - You can switch styles to that of Ghastly, to Ghastlier, or to Ghastliest, without the need to buy 3 seperate hats
  - Get a **Vintage Pyrovision Goggles**. If you're feeling rich, you can opt for the slightly rarer **Unique Pyrovision Goggles**
  - Get a HHHH's Headtaker if you want the weapon

    - You can get a clean (tradable one) for 3 keys
  - Get a Spine-Cooling Skull

    - If you have teh monies, 26 keys can get you a tradable one for 23-28 keys
    - If you don't, you can get untradables for 2 - 4 refined + gift wrap

Comment: Why would `Unique Pyrovision Goggles` be more expensive?  Players can still get the unique one by dominating someone who is wearing either version, but the Vintage one hasn't been available since mid-2012.

Comment: Side note: It's spell "Gibus" not Ghibus.  The Spine-Cooling Skull is only one of its 3 variants of the [2011 Spine-Chilling Skull](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Spine-Chilling_Skull_2011)... and if you get the one named Spine-Chilling Skull 2011, it has all 3 variants as different styles.  The other two variants are `Spine-Twisting` and `Spine-Tingling`.

Comment: @Powerlord A clean (tradable) unique Pyrovision Goggles is considered to be 1.33 refined, but the Vintage ones are considered 1-2 scrap each.  Unique Pyrovision Goggles from the achievement can only be traded via giftwrap, and why would you spend $2.00 to get a giftwrapped version instead of a clean Vintage one for $0.02

Comment: @Powerlord I should clarify. You can receive the Pyrovision goggles as a random drop, so it drops in a "clean" format (tradable and craftable)

Comment: This should probably be reported to Valve, then, as neither it nor the Gibus are supposed to be in the standard drop list.

Comment: @Powerlord What do you mean it's not supposed to be in the standard drop list? Achievement items are available as drops from the drop system (some are).

Comment: Achievement hats aren't supposed to be, as hats are rare drops.

Comment: The Uncraftable Skull (that has the 3 craftable ones) is only around 7 USD on the market.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Steam Forums thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1802992) from back in 2011, you can reset achievements by using the Steam Achievement Manager, because achievements are stored locally.  Unfortunately, the item drops are stored on the Steam Inventory server, so you would not be able to get your items again.

The next best option however, since TF2 is free-to-play, would be to create another Steam account and re-unlock those achievements.

Comment: Creating a new account is not a good option.  It is a horrible option, because you are now forcing the user to abandon an account for the sake of 3 items that can be easily obtained through trading with other players.

Comment: It's an option if trading is out of the question, i.e. doesn't want to trade.

Comment: The user never mentioned anything regarding trading, so you cannot assume the user wouldn't want to trade.

Comment: He could just start a new account,get the items there and trade them back to his main account. Not the worst idea imo.

Comment: @gruntswilldie Achievement items cannot be traded without the use of giftwrap.  Are you telling me it'd be worth paying $2.00 for each $0.03 items to get them back to his main account? That's probably the worst idea, since the cost of getting 3 gift wrap is enough to get him the items he was looking for in the first place in tradable condition

Comment: @meme scientist I did not know the price for these items was so low.

Comment: The ghibus isn't expensive, neither is the pyrovision goggles, the only exception is the haunted metal scrap, which is only expensive if it's actually tradable. But since this answer implies creating a new account, it will have the untradable version, which is worth nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is playing TF2 from a different computer, and getting the achivements again

Comment: This would associate the items with a different account, so unless you spent money from that new computer to get a premium account and enable trading, there would be no way to transfer the items back to the account I use on my primary computer.